# Viewport behavior with Ipad mini 4 (Bootstrap 3)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design, viewport

I am developing website to responsive for mobile and tables devices. i was using Chrome Console to debug and re-size screen to make responsive design.What i have done. my design working on the console view(Chrome Mobile devices test) but when i run to actual device on ipad mini 4 what i get response.
[image]
 it's looking like scale problem. i am using mata tag. here is how i am using. `<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0/>` In above screenshot you can see the hole cover my container at left side and pretty much space at right side.I serached on it but i did not get enough acknowledge to clear the problem .Kindly help me to make my acknowledge to next level.  Thanks...

Comment: Could you explain better to help? Scroll appears you? Thank you @user2219168

Comment: no any scroll appears.